# Role of "otherwise" in conditional sentences

Tags: conditionals

I have a question about this test question:

> Chemotherapy given at the same time as radiation therapy can help patients with a certain type of lung cancer live nearly 50 percent longer than they ........ otherwise if the same treatment ...... differently.
>
> 1. may have / will be given
> 2. might have / was given
> 3. could have had / would be given
> 4. would have had / would have been given

The answer is 2.

Why did it use "might have"? Why not for example "might"?

> ... help them live longer than they might have

What?! They might have lived? In this way it won't be a 2nd conditional. Using "was given" is correct ***I think***, because he is talking about an **imagination** and a thought in the present tense and it is similar to the concept of conditional sentences type 2.

Comment: You're right, but the main reason is to parallel "Chemotherapy **given** at the same time with **given differently**. (I'd write given at different times, not differently.)

Comment: @YosefBaskin But, there is an ( if ). You mean it isn't a Conditional sentence?

Comment: Yes, it's conditional, and the word "otherwise" does not play into the question or do much in the sentence. "Chemotherapy given" is short for Chemotherapy which **was given**, and there's your parallel.

Comment: OK, Thank you.can you please explain why it has used "might have" ?

Comment: Chemotherapy was given with radiation. But what about separately? Not as good, but it **might have** been as good? No, together helped with much longer life.

Comment: This site frowns on chatting, but one last thought: patients got treatments at the same time or not, but one system only. When we compare one to the other, that's imagining one patient with the better treatment who **might have** lived longer on average (in theory). We don't actually know.

Comment: _Might_ is just as good as _might have_, but it wasn't one of the options on the question, was it?

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I believe "Chemotherapy given" is actually short for "Chemotherapy that was given."

Comment: Mahdi, I wouldn't have used "might **have**" in this sentence, but a lot of people writing in English are a little sloppy.  The speaker's time point of view is a bit mixed up, so I understand your unhappiness.  But I've seen worse test questions in my life.

Comment: @aparente001 There’s nothing sloppy at all about that aspect of the question!